# how to make sure the onDestroy method is called when the user exits

Tags: android

I having trouble calling the onDestroy() method in my code.
The aim of my code is to write two txt files when the user exits the app by using the button at the bottom of the screen. This can save their progress.
It then loads it on the OnCreate() method
However the OnDestroy() method doesn't get called
Is there anyway to force this to happen when the exit button is pressed on the phone?
The main body of the code is not included because it is not important to my question. Thank you.
Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_question);
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("correct.txt");
        //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String strLine = null;
        int x=0;


        while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
            arrayCorrect[x]=strLine;
            x++;

        }


        //Log.i("File Reading stuff", "success = " + "hell");

    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {//ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("incorrect.txt");
        //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String strLine = null;
        int x=0;


        while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
            arrayIncorrect[x]=strLine;
            x++;

        }


        //Log.i("File Reading stuff", "success = " + "hell");

    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {//ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass
    try{
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("correct.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        // Write the string to the file
        for(int x=0; x<arrayCorrect.length; x++) {
            osw.write(arrayCorrect[x] + "\n");
        }

   /* ensure that everything is
    * really written out and close */
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("incorrect.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        // Write the string to the file
        for(int x=0; x<arrayIncorrect.length; x++) {
            osw.write(arrayIncorrect[x] + "\n");
        }

   /* ensure that everything is
    * really written out and close */
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    // startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),second.class));
}
```

Comment: do it at `onStop()`, yeah its going to be called soo many times, but `onDestroy()` will get called eventually, but not always though, but yeah they are called when the activity is destroyed.. log values there to check if truely they are triggered

Comment: I'm guessing that any code written after the super.onDestroy() is never called, because onDestroy finishes the app completely. Anything called afterwards is ignored.

Comment: the `onDestroy` life cycle won't be called when press exit button because you activity are not destroyed. `onStop`/`onResume` is the callback you should handle for your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting that code in the onDestroy method. You should instead start a background service on the onPause method.